# How to prevent Apache writing double backslashes into error log file?

Tags: apache, logging

Apache is writing strings with double slashes to the error log, like so:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error:
Call to undefined method Selector\\Fieldset\\SelectionForm 
... thrown in module\\Selector\\src\\Selection\\SelectionDataMapper.php 
on line 26, referer: http://...c=start
```

Is there a way to make Apache write single slashes?

Software:

- Windows 10 Version 1703
- Apache 2.4.26 (Win64)
- PHP Version 7.1.6

and I have this in my `VirtualHost` directive:

```
ErrorLog "logs/portal-error.log"
```

Comment: That's usually how it's written since backslash + some characters are control characters. Ex: `\n` is a new line, `\t` is a tab etc. If it's just in the error log, does it matter?

Comment: Thanks.. can someone confirm/refute that double slashes are written that way on Windows/Linux platforms, and it's not just me.  I think on my old machine (now gone) I had single slashes but can't verify

Comment: This is a Windows thing, since Linux is using forward slashes in paths.

Comment: It's escaping the backslash. Why? No idea. Probably a Windows specific bug.

Comment: If someone, like me, gets here trying to figure out double slashes breaking JSON lines in apache error logs, I don't think there's a way to fix it. It's not PHP's (or your runtime's) fault. Apache doubles backslashes even if you use `%M` as your log format. I'd hope they had a binary log option where they just relay the raw bytes to the file/stdout.